# React получить значение setState из другого компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты, setstate

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form className="form">
        <h1 className="form__title">React</h1>
        <div className="form-wrap">
          <label>Ваш номер телефона</label>
          <input className="form__input" placeholder="+7 (###) ### - ## - ##" />
          <Button />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var Button = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  receiveCode: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({visible: true})
  },
  render: function () {
    var visible = this.state.visible;
    return (
      <div className="buttons">
        <input type="submit" className="form__btn" onClick={this.receiveCode} value={visible ? 'Отправить код' : 'Получить код'} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Мне нужно в компоненте App получить значение visible из компонента Button. Т.е использовать в классе для проверки на значение true/false

Answer (score 0):

- Создайте `state` с значением `visible` и метод `receiveCode` в классе `App`.
- Передайте метод `receiveCode` и `state` как `props` компоненту `Button`.
- Вызывайте в `Button` метод `receiveCode` из пропсов.